# Should you write unit tests for code that tests application behavior?

Tags: unit-testing

I'm wondering if you should or should not write unit tests for code that's part of the main application and can be called by the customer even though the code is only responsible for stress testing part of the application.

Actually, I should maybe explain why I'm asking: I used to have the opinion all production code should have unit tests no matter what the code does. But I now got two people telling me not to write unit tests for code like this and one of them is a person that teaches others about TDD and unit testing and whom I respect a lot. His explanation was:
'The purpose of unit tests is to verify good design practices, provide internal documentation of understanding of requirements and design decisions, and serve as a continuous proof of functional correctness of units of code (not necessarily the functional correctness of the entire deliverable). That had nothing to do with stress tests, that are only aimed to produce an artifact of proof of performance or reliability.'

So I'm now really confused if my thinking of all production code needing unit tests was wrong for years.

Answer (score 0):

You **unit** test all *units* within your production code base.

It doesn't matter what that each *unit* does in the end. If the *unit* is required to deliver some sort of functionality that is part of your product, then you better test that *unit*.

That is what **production** code is about: it is all code that defines your *product* that your customer pays money for, to do what it is supposed to do.

Alternatively, look at this from the point of the customer: what if he wants to run some stress tests, for example to measure how his setup works. And then, these tests break. Because you didn't test that feature, albeit it is available to the customer?! Think that through: what would you be telling your customers when they use something that "officially exists" in the product, and is somehow documented ... but then doesn't work?

If at all, you could get maybe get away by stating "we have that stress test feature, but it is not officially supported", but that simply doesn't look to good in your sales flyers. And again: testing things upfront is key here. There is nothing worse than **being in need** of using feature X, to then figure "oopsie, feature X is currently broken".

Comment: I had exactly the same opinion and updated my question to show why I'm now questioning myself.

Comment: @CantrianBear I dont think your edit changes much. My main point is: you deliver a function to your customers. It doesn't matter what that function is. Again: if you dont have good tests for that *feature*, and you ask a customer to run that, and then things dont work, what will you tell the customer? Maybe you need different kind of testing, but no matter how: you want to have a certain confidence that "that code" works.